# What are the benefits of running Gnome 3 + awesome compared with awesome alone?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, awesome

What are the benefits to running awesome as my window manager in Gnome 3? I am interested in identifying what features/functionality gnome3+awesome provides that can not be easily (if not identical) replicated running awesome all by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnome provides services (such as Gnome keyring, GConf, PolicyKit integration, etc.) that some programs use as well as additional features like theme application and application autostarting. If you use programs that make use of those services and you don't have Gnome, you may miss out on some functionality. Depending on what you use, it might be critical, or you might never miss it.